# Why doesn't \n make a new line char if it is taken from file input?

Tags: c, file-io, newline

If we write in the code `char arg[]="hello\nworld";` it's fine, when we print string `arg` we get a new line in between `hello` and `world`.

But if we scan this string `hello\nworld` from console or from a text file and store it in a buffer, and if we print that we don't get a new line there and `\n` is printed as it is, i.e: `hello\nworld`.

May be here '`\`' and '`n`' are taken as different characters, but why this variation? I'm not getting it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escape sequences in character or string constants (like `"\n"`) are handled by the *compiler*. If you read the sequence `'\'` and `'n'` from a file, that just two characters, reading from a file does no parsing of the contents (with the exception of possible newline conversion, and here I talk about *actual* newlines, character code `10` in [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)).